# load-success never fired in Bootstrap-table

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table

I'm new to Bootstrap-table. I can't `load-success` to be fired:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {    
  var $table = $('#table');
  alert('document loaded');
  $table.on('load-success.bs.table', function(e, data){          
    alert('table loaded');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table data-toolbar="#toolbar" data-toggle="table"  data-search="true" 
    data-row-style="rowStyle" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id" data-visible='false'>id</td>
      <th>A</th>
      <th data-sortable='true'>B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried `$table.on('load-error.bs.table'`, `$table.on('all.bs.table'` etc... but it's never fired. My table appears normally on the screen though.

However, I can do : `$table.on('click-row.bs.table'` and it's working but I need to access this table as soon as it's loaded.

Comment: which version did you use?

Comment: the last one (I've re-downloaded it just now).

Comment: load-success.bs.table that function worked on remote data loading

Comment: Ah that's why! So how do you trigger for example the `function rowStyle()`  if you need to do post-loading styling?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () {
  function rowStyle(row, index) { alert("styling"); }); });` isn't triggered in fact.

Comment: Apparently, I can't do it: I need to do `<script>function rowStyle(...`. If I do `<script>$(document).ready(function(){ function rowStyle(...` it must confuse `Bootstrap-table` which didn't find the function. Okay